# need help on insert new contact into access mdb from delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access

I want to write an app that is an address book and uses a access .mdb file. I know how to insert a new contact into the database, but i do't know how to edit a contact. I put my test project in here [AddressBookTest.zip](http://rigo.ro/temp/AddressBookTest.zip). Any help is welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for INSERT must do This:

```
      qryAux.SQL.Text:='INSERT INTO tblContacts(FirstName, LastName) VALUES( ' +
        QuotedStr(frmEd.edFirstName.Text) + ',' +
        QuotedStr(frmEd.edLastName.Text) + ')';
```

Here is correct for insert the two values.

In Edit mode, for retrieve values from DB, you must execute the **Open**, not the **ExecSQL**.
And after do the **Open**, you must test if the record is finded. 
See this code:

```
   qryAux.Open;

   // Finded?
   if not (qryAux.Eof) then begin
     frmEd.edFirstName.Text:=qryAux.FieldByName('FirstName').AsString;
     frmEd.edLastName.Text:=qryAux.FieldByName('LastName').AsString;
   end;
```

Regards.

---

Neftalí -Germán Estévez-

Comment: NOTE:
Also, you can use parameters in the aryAux Query; Using paramaters it's not needed use QuotedStr.

-> qryAux.SQL.Text:='INSERT INTO tblContacts(FirstName, LastName) VALUES(:fist, :last)';

Comment: You do not need to supply the field names in an INSERT statement, as long as you are supplying values for all of the fields, in order.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using SQL commands instead of Edit/Insert/Post. Therefore what you need is the UPDATE command:

```
UPDATE tblContacts
SET FirstName = '''+frmEd.edFirstName.Text+''''
WHERE ID=10
```

To add more than one value, separate with commas, eg.

```
SET FirstName = 'John', LastName = 'Smith'
```